# SceneKit loading big 3D model(1GB)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, scenekit, 3d-model

I am new to 3D world, and in my application i need load big 3d model nearly 1GB. In general what are the different ways/approaches to load big models in Scenkit/unity?

Comment: I cannot see that working on an iOS device.  You'll have to reduce the model size considerably.

Comment: agree with above comment, most iOS devices only have 1gb of ram, so not sure how you are going to load it up